# Installing Linux Perf tools on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with WSL2

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to set up Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using WSL 2 on my Windows machine in order to be able to run performance experiments across a version of Linux and Windows, and as part of this I intended to install the `perf` tool.

In order to do so, I read that the packages `linux-tools-common` and `linux-tools-generic` would be needed. I installed these using `apt install`, and it did indeed result in `perf` being installed. However if I try to run the tool, I get presented with the following prompt:

```bsh
$ perf --version
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 5.4.72-microsoft

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
    linux-cloud-tools-5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-standard-WSL2
    linux-cloud-tools-standard-WSL2
```

However, none of these packages exist within the apt repositories and I cannot find any references to such packages.

Has anybody gone through setting up Linux `perf` on WSL2 or would be able to offer me advice on how best to solve this issue?

Comment: @Biswapriyo's answer here worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237123/is-there-any-method-to-run-perf-under-wsl

Answer (score 2):

Perf is currently not supported by WSL2, because it has a custom kernel which does not support hardware counters. You can install perf manually, but it won't give you the expected results.
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4678
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/329
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3225

Comment: Those issues are already closed, but there is new one:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8480